# why Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

hi a im using codeigniter and Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery

in my jquery i define my auto complete like this

```
    a = $('.city').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: "<? echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>home/auth/city_autocomplete",
    });
```

`.city`  is the class name of my input field

my action `city_autocomplete` is this

```
    function city_autocomplete(){

        $array = array('query'=>'Li','suggestions' => array('Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania'));                       
        echo  json_encode($array) ;
    }
```

i have hard corded values here

my json_encoded array is this

```
{"query":"Li","suggestions":["Liberia","Libyan Arab Jamahiriya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania"]}
```

when i enter a letter in city input box , i can see the above response json array  , but the problem is no suggesion vlues is displayed . when i check

```
<div id="AutocompleteContainter_c6592" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 590.85px; left: 533.383px;">
```

there is no options

why is this happening , i have done this before exactly the same way and it worked perfectly , why the suggessons not showing . please help me ............... :(

UPDATE

this is the library i am using

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't allow query parameters in config.php of CI
allow the query parameters

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

OR user ajax post method

or replace the line in jquery.autocomplete.js

```
$.get(this.serviceUrl, me.options.params, function(txt) { me.processResponse(txt); }, 'text');
```

to

```
$.post(this.serviceUrl, me.options.params, function(txt) { me.processResponse(txt); }, 'text');
```